# .change() not firing .on() jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onchange

I need to manually make call to `.change()` to do some operation and i have written an .`on()` for this functionality for other `input` controls. But for `DatePicker` column i need to fire it manually as it's not firing whenever date is set to textbox.

```
$('input.JDateCtrl').datepicker({        
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
        debugger;
        //$(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').val(dateText);
        $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').attr('value', dateText);
        var ctrlID = $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').attr('id');
        $('#' + ctrlID).trigger('change');
       // $('#' + ctrlID).change(); // Tried it too
    }
 });
```

And `.on()` is as below.

```
  $jQuery(document).on('change', '.JAsyncUpdateTxt', function () {
       // Some Operations being performed in this block
   });
```

But `.on()` is not firing whenever i make trigger `change` event.

*P.S* : its already wrapped inside `$jQuery(document).ready();`

Comment: You're triggering a change on a ID, but the event handler uses a class. When triggering event handlers, use the same selector that the handler was bound with.

Comment: Check the console you'll see: Uncaught ReferenceError: $jQuery is not defined

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward - Probably, but it's darn  easy to use noConflict to map jQuery to just about anything, even `$jQuery` if one wanted to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', '.JAsyncUpdateTxt', function () {
       // Some Operations being performed in this block
   });
```

Remove **'jQuery'**. Use any one.

Comment: @MayankPathak, Glad to help you. If you want to use $Jquery, Use noConflict().

Comment: `$jQuery` is another Global selector being used in application to access `jQuery`...i have added JqueryUi as separate functionality that's why this confusion happened..

Answer (score 1):

Please put your .on() first then .datepicker as below:-

```
$(document).on('change', '.JAsyncUpdateTxt', function () {
   // Some Operations being performed in this block
});


$('input.JDateCtrl').datepicker({        
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
    debugger;
    //$(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').val(dateText);
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').attr('value', dateText);
    var ctrlID = $(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').attr('id');
    $('#' + ctrlID).trigger('change');
   // $('#' + ctrlID).change(); // Tried it too
}
});
```

I think this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on('change', '.JAsyncUpdateTxt', function () {
       // Some Operations being performed in this block
   });
```

remove jquery use one either jquery or $